# Regexp in python, lost in backslash

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I have this pattern, and this windows filename I want to match it to. Names changed to protect the innocent: [a-zA-Z]+ was replaced with successive letters of the alphabet.

```
pattern = "C:\\\\a\\\\b\\\\c\\\\d\\\\e f\\\\(g|h|i)\\\\j k\\\\l\\\\m\\\\(n\\\\(o|p)|q)\\\\.*\.sql)"

str = "C:\\a\\b\\c\\d\\e f\\h\\j k\\l\\m\\n\\o\\z_zz.function.sql"
```

But, python complains about an unmatched paren. I don't know why. The position it gives me (62) also doesn't line up with any of my parens, but if I had to guess I'd say one of the many backslashes is accidentally escaping (g or (o when I didn't want it to, but adding more backslashes in front of those hasn't helped.

Comment: Tip:  You can use the "raw" string notation in order to cut down on the number of backslashes you need.  E.g.  `r'C:\a\b'` == `'C:\\a\\b'`

Comment: Use raw string literals if you have to deal with literal backslashes.

Comment: I originally avoided that because of confusion resulting from paths beginning with s, d, w, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backslashes are all properly escaped.  The position it gives (62) **does** match up with a paren, the last one to be specific:

```
>>> pattern = "C:\\\\a\\\\b\\\\c\\\\d\\\\e f\\\\(g|h|i)\\\\j k\\\\l\\\\m\\\\(n\\\\(o|p)|q)\\\\.*\.sql)"
>>> pattern[62]
')'
>>> len(pattern)
63
```

So match that right paren with a left paren where you want your `group` to be, or remove the last paren from you pattern.

Comment: Wow, it's so obvious. Thanks!